# Function to get a 'post selector' UI?

Tags: wp-admin

I have a custom plugin page and I want users to be able to select posts/pages and add them to a list.

I was hoping to use the same UI as found on the Appearance > Menus Page which I picture below

[image: Desired UI]

Is there a function to specifically print this UI into the page?

Comment: Thomas, I'm not sure if this does exist as I've never actually checked, but in instances like this I usually use Select2 inputs where the user starts typing and once there's at least 3 letters an AJAX search starts executing and returns matching results.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no existing function available for an equivalent UI for posts or pages.

The whole UI in your screenshot is provided by the `post_categories_meta_box()` function, which uses `wp_category_checklist()` internally for the actual checkboxes, which implements the `Walker_Category_Checklist` class. All of these are built for listing terms as checkboxes, and can't be repurposed for listing posts.

You would need to implement this yourself (although if you look at the source for `post_categories_meta_box()` you might be able to use matching markup to ensure visual consistency.